# Spree Split order into two shipments if one of the line items is backorder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, spree-3.1

I'm creating a Spree application using Spree version 3.1 and i'm facing an issue where spree split order into two shipments with double shipping cost if any line item of the order is out of stock even if i'm using

```
Rails.application.config.spree.stock_splitters = []
```

which according to documentation prevent order splitting

> Or if you don't want to split packages just set the option above to an
>   empty array. e.g. a store with the following configuration in spree.rb
>   won't have any package splitted.

any solution for this issue ?!

Comment: It seems there's already [an open issue](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/8204) about this bug in the project, which you commented on before posting here. Given the bug's description, is it a viable option for you to just downgrade to spree `3.0.x` until fixed?

Comment: I've solved this issue by overriding register stock splitter initializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue by overriding register stock splitter initializer

```
initializer 'spree.register.stock_splitters' do |app|
  app.config.spree.stock_splitters = []
end
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed Ali, Could you please let me know how did you resolve it actually, as I am getting the error as below.


<top (required)>': undefined method `initializer' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: add the above code to engine.rb file, you can also add Rails.application.config.spree.stock_splitters = []
 to spree.rb

Answer (score 0):

This fix:

**Turn off split shipments**

If you don't want to split packages in any case, you can set the config.spree.stock_splitters option to an empty array:

```
Rails.application.config.spree.stock_splitters = []
```

As documented here seems to solve it for me.

https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/master/guides/source/developers/shipments/split-shipments.html.md